# router-view adds unwanted attribute on html element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a route structure similar to this :

```
[
  {
      path: '/level1/:prop1',
      props: ['prop1'],
      component: () => import('@/component/Level1Component'),
      children: [
         {
            path:'level2/:prop2',
            props: ['prop1', 'prop2']
            component: () => import('@/component/Level2Component')
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The main page has the router-view for `Level1Component`.

`Level1Component` has a router-view for `Level2Component`:

```
<script>
export default {
   name : 'Level1Component',
   props: ['prop1']
}
</script>
<template>
   <div>
      <h1>level 1 : {{ prop1 }}</h1>
      <router-view />
   </div>
</template>
```

And this is `Level2Component`:

```
<script>
export default {
   name : 'Level2Component',
   props: ['prop1', 'prop2']
}
</script>
<template>
   <div>
      <h2>level 2 : {{ prop1 }} - {{ prop2 }}</h2>
   </div>
</template>
```

Problem is, `Level1Component` is rendered with a `prop2` attribute from the route. It is added as an attribute because there's no `prop2` defined in `Level1Component`:

```
<!-- route /level1/foo/level2/bar -->
<div prop2="bar"> <!-- this is Level1Component. Attribute props2 is invalid -->
  <h1>level1 : foo</h1>
  <div> <!-- this is Level2Component -->
     <h2>level2 : foo - bar</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to add `prop2` to `Level1Component` because it has no use for it. I would expect the route component to receive only the data idientified on the prop of his own level in the route definition.

Is there any way to disable this attribute addition, or at least prefix it with `data-` so it yields valid html ?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but try changing the level 2 path to `level2/:prop2`; you needn't repeat the parent path.

Comment: @DecadeMoon true, I missed that. Real code is as you said. I'll update the question.